# Bootstrap 3.2.0: Open dropdown menu with javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, triggers, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle

I'm having difficulty opening a dropdown menu with bootstrap 3.2.0 and javascript. Here is the html (added dynamically with javascript to dom):

```
<ul id="assigned" class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li id="shopping-cart-dropdown" class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" id="dropdown-toggle" class="dropdown-toggle button-assigned" data-toggle="dropdown">
         <span class="span-assigned">(0/5)</span>
         <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu assigned-menu" role="menu">
         <p class="assigned-info">
            <span class="bold">You have 5 assignments available.</span>
         </p>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And Javascripts I've tried so far:

```
$("#shopping-cart-dropdown").addClass("open"); //open class not added in dom. bootstrap prevents this?

$("#dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle"); //nothing happens

$("#dropdown-toggle").click(); //no luck either

$(".assigned-menu").css("display", "block"); //this displays the dropdown but its not closable forever
var dd = $('#shopping-cart-dropdown');
dd.closable = true; //I can't make it closable with this code
```

**Edit**: When I first fire the toggle after I create the dropdown contents with

```
$("#dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle");
```

It works

But when I call the same function again it doesnt. Here is the function that refreshes dropdown contents (as well as first time creating them):

```
    for (var cnt = 0; cnt < this.AssignedRooms.length; cnt++) {
        var litext = "";
        litext += "<div class='assigned-item'  id='assigned-room" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].RoomNo + "' " + "building-no='" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].BuildingNo + "'" + " floor-no='" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].FloorNo + "' room-no='" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].RoomNo + "'>";
        litext += (this.EnableCampus ? "<span class='small bold'>Building </span><span class='small'>" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].BuildingNo + ", </span>" : "");
        litext += "<span class='small bold'>Floor </span><span class='small'>" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].FloorNo + "</span>, ";
        litext += "<span class='small bold'>Room </span><span class='small'>" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].RoomNo + "</span>";
        litext += "</div>";
        litext += "<div class='assigned-cancel'  id='assigned-room-cancel" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].RoomNo + "' " + "building-no='" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].BuildingNo + "'" + " floor-no='" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].FloorNo + "' room-no='" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].RoomNo + "'>";
        litext += "<img src='../../PickContent/img/cancel-small.png' title='Cancel Room " + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].RoomNo + "'/>";
        litext += "</div>";
        html += "<li class='assigned-list-item'>" + litext + "</li>";
    }

    $("#assigned ul.dropdown-menu").html(html);

    if (full) {
        $("#dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle");
    }
```

Comment: $("#dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle"); and $("#dropdown-toggle").click(); should work just fine http://jsfiddle.net/cvjuxz3g/, make sure the element is already in DOM before calling the script

Comment: Interestingly, when I call $("#dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle"); the first time I create the contents of dropdown it works. But doesn't get fired after that when I refresh the contents of dropdown and fire it from anywhere in the code. The only thing happens is the link to activate the dropdown gets highlighted (color gets brighter)

Comment: I should add that when I check if the dropdown is there or not before firing the toggle second time I can see the element is there.

Comment: Can you show the code for refresh the contents of dropdown?

Comment: I use the same code to refresh the contents as well as first time creating them. I've edited original post to show you. I call the function with full=true to try opening the dropdown.

Comment: May I know where do you call the refresh function? Is it inside a link/button click event?

Comment: Upgrade to Bootstrap v3.3.0 (or v3.3.1 if you can wait a few days)

Comment: @cvrebert: Upgrade to bootstrap 3.3.0 didn't fix the problem. Can you provide a link to a solution with this upgrade?

Comment: @BarışÜrüm Was just a general suggestion/guess; I don't have a solution.

Comment: At this moment only solution seems to be to show the dropdown forcibly with $(".assigned-menu").css("display", "block"); and somehow find a way to make the menu closable. How can I make the menu closable after forcibly opening the dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

You are using bootstrap 3.2. You don't need extra JavaScript to make the drop down work.

If it is not working with pure Bootstrap. Make sure you have Jquery included as well as Bootstrap. Jquery is REQUIRED for the drop down to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It seems you have not read the entire question thoroughly before giving this answer. The question is about opening the dropdown explicitly with javascript code.

Comment: @BarışÜrüm Bootstrap contains Javascript code. To add additional code for something that already is in place is redundant. As long as your classes are named correctly and html is structured right, the frameworks Javascript will function correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose your refresh function is inside a link/button click event handler.
Try adding `return false;` at the end of the function to prevents the browser from performing the default action for that link/button.

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    ...
    for (var cnt = 0; cnt < this.AssignedRooms.length; cnt++) {
        var litext = "";
        litext += "<div class='assigned-item'  id='assigned-room" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].RoomNo + "' " + "building-no='" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].BuildingNo + "'" + " floor-no='" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].FloorNo + "' room-no='" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].RoomNo + "'>";
        litext += (this.EnableCampus ? "<span class='small bold'>Building </span><span class='small'>" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].BuildingNo + ", </span>" : "");
        litext += "<span class='small bold'>Floor </span><span class='small'>" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].FloorNo + "</span>, ";
        litext += "<span class='small bold'>Room </span><span class='small'>" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].RoomNo + "</span>";
        litext += "</div>";
        litext += "<div class='assigned-cancel'  id='assigned-room-cancel" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].RoomNo + "' " + "building-no='" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].BuildingNo + "'" + " floor-no='" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].FloorNo + "' room-no='" + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].RoomNo + "'>";
        litext += "<img src='../../PickContent/img/cancel-small.png' title='Cancel Room " + this.AssignedRooms[cnt].RoomNo + "'/>";
        litext += "</div>";
        html += "<li class='assigned-list-item'>" + litext + "</li>";
    }

    $("#assigned ul.dropdown-menu").html(html);

    if (full) {
        $("#dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle");
    }
    ...

    return false; //Add this line
});
```